# Loading points and polylines into PostGIS database and creating connectivity between them using topology?

Tags: postgis, topology, distribution

I am new in PostGIS, and I am trying to create connectivity(using topology) between 3 sets of points and polyline to model an electrical distribution network.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229643/where-does-postgis-store-its-topology-tables

Comment: If you're data is already topologically correct and connected, you could possibly use the PGRouting tools to build the connectivity and the routing functions could give you what you need ... maybe @dkastl would have some thoughts...

Answer (score 1):

The question you're asking is not very specific, and as such, you're probably best off getting started, and coming back to ask questions when you find specific issues.

I recommend you read these as a starting point:

1. The [documentation on PostGIS Topology](http://postgis.net/docs/Topology.html)
2. A [tutorial on PostGIS Topology](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/2.4.11/en/chapters/topology.html).

I haven't run through these, and there doesn't seem to be much material online, but that might actually be an indication of how easy it is to do!

Good luck.